# Attempting to read LVM disk in ubuntu

Tags: mount, lvm, ext3

I pulled a disk formatted in LVM from a NAS after the device failed, and need to recover the data, but I can't seem to get it to mount. 
This is the closest I got:

```
root@peter-desktop:/home/peter# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdd5   VG c   lvm2 [1.82 TiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [1.82 TiB] / in use: 1 [1.82 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
root@peter-desktop:/home/peter# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "c" using metadata type lvm2
root@peter-desktop:/home/peter# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/c/c' [1.82 TiB] inherit
root@peter-desktop:/home/peter# mount -t ext3 /dev/c/c /mnt/fcroot
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/c-c,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here? Is the drive corrupt? The filesystem type was confirmed to be ext3 using the `file` command

```
root@peter-desktop:/home/peter# file -sL /dev/c/c 
/dev/c/c: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=3ecd91ba-161a-4d7f-bac7-a3b1a7095be4, volume name "c" (large files)
```

and the last relevant errors in the `dmesg` log appear to be

```
EXT3-fs (dm-3): error: bad blocksize 16384
```

I don't normally deal with command line mounting, but since the GUI couldn't mount the drive I didn't really have a choice, so please explain any code and I'll do my best to understand it.

Comment: Looks like it's ext3

`root@peter-desktop:/home/peter# file -sL /dev/c/c`

`/dev/c/c: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=3ecd91ba-161a-4d7f-bac7-a3b1a7095be4, volume name "c" (large files)`

Comment: So it should have mounted with `mount -t ext3 /dev/c/c /mnt/fcroot` right? But as I posted in the question, it didn't.

Comment: fsck gave the message: `fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/c/c
Possibly non-existent device?` EDIT: just activated the volume and tried again and now it seems to be doing something /EDIT.
I also checked dmesg, but don't really know what it all measn, the last few errors were `EXT3-fs (dm-3): error: bad blocksize 16384`.

Comment: fsck finished, found Free blocks count wrong and Free inodes count wrong, and repaired them, but I still can't mount the drive, same error.

Comment: That was it! the ReadyNAS uses 16KB block sizes, but x86 only supports 4KB blocks (natively). I was able to use `fuseext2` to mount the drive. Thanks for your help - If you want to put it into an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the EXT3-fs device mapper error in dmesg, it seems that this is a known issue with mounting ext filesystems from certain ReadyNAS devices (which use 16k block size) on x86 systems (which have a 4k ext3 block size limit).

There is a suggested workaround in a post by user 'kernst' on the ReadyNAS user forum [Using fuse-ext2 to access ReadyNAS-formatted ext3](http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=42339#p239474). The basic steps are

- install the fuseext2 package (which should be available from the 'universe' repository)
- mount the volume containing the ext3 filesystem using `fuseext2`

Since you are trying to mount an LVM logical volume rather than a plain block device the format of the `fuseext2` command should be something like

```
fuseext2 -o ro,allow_other /dev/c/c /mnt/fcroot
```

where `/dev/c/c` is the */dev/vg/lv* block device name of your volume. When you are done, you can cleanly unmount the filesystem using

```
fusermount -u /mnt/fcroot
```

Currently this workaround only supports read-only access. There were some search results suggesting that newer 3.x Linux kernels have native support of ext3 block sizes above 4k, but I was not able to confirm that (or whether it helps in this situation, without accompanying changes in page size).